# Determine solubility of $x^2 \equiv a$ (mod $p$) for large $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to determine the solubility of the following two congruences

$x^2 \equiv -286 $ (mod $4272943$)

$x^2 \equiv -67469 $ (mod $4272949$)

Both the mod numbers are primes. $4272943$ is $3$ mod $4$ and $4272949$ is $1$ mod $4$ (wonder if this has anything to do with the problem?) I think the best way to approach this is to use Euler's criteria i.e. $x^2 \equiv a$ mod $p$ is soluble iff $a^\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 1$ mod $p$. The problem I have is how can I show the latter condition is fulfilled for such large values of $p$?

Comment: You use the "Jacobi reciprocity law", it is essentially just like Euclid's algorithm, so it runs at exceptional fast logarithmic time.

Comment: If you already know the moduli are prime, it's equally speedy to use [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) to test Euler's criterion.